# Receiving acknowledgements using IoT Hub

Tags: azure-iot-hub, azure-iot-sdk

When using DeviceClient I can send messages using SendEvent and files using SendBlob. But I did not find a way to receive acknowledgement that messages/files have been received by Azure IoT Hub?

The only way I found to solve this is using serviceClient.GetFileNotificationReceiver().
Am I missing something or is this the only way?

Also it seems I need SharedAccessKeyName to use ServiceClient. But this is not present in e.g. tokens created by DeviceExplorer (which I use for DeviceClient). Any advice is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

For Java and C sdks there are [IotHubEventCallback](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/java/api/com.microsoft.azure.sdk.iot.device._iot_hub_event_callback) and [IOTHUB_CLIENT_EVENT_CONFIRMATION_CALLBACK](https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-arduino/blob/master/src/sdk/iothub_client_ll.h) but for C# there is no such interface implemented.

So, for C#, a message will be sent successfully if DeviceClient.SendEventAsync() without throwing any exception, otherwise it fails.

Or you can utilize [Event Hub-compatible endpoint to monitor the status of operations on your IoT hub](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-operations-monitoring), D2C message, file upload...

For ServiceClient, you need Azure IoT Hub connection string, not device connection string. You can find it in Configuration of Device Explorer:

[image]